# Why the following conditional ternary operator does not work?

Tags: javascript

I am doing this in order to get the row value of the seating array to be assigned to row.

```
this.mylistings.push({
   row: data.ticket.seating?data.ticket.seating[0].row:'',       
})
```

but the above way does not set the value of the seating is null.

Comment: guys why downvote ? am i doing something basing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it, it works fine.  Had you provided a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example you would see that.  Here is the example I created.  If you feel I've missed something please make your own example like this which shows the problem.

```js
var data = {
  ticket: {
    seating: [
      {row: 1}
    ]
  }
};

var x = {
   row: data.ticket.seating?data.ticket.seating[0].row:'',       
}

console.log(x);
```